# TouchEvent illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, events, mocha.js, jsdom

Running in a jsdom command line interface for unit tests.

```
const event = new window.TouchEvent('touchstart');
```

> TypeError: Illegal constructor

Why is this not working?
According to this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event) list it should work via the constructor.

This works fine:

```
const event = new window.MouseEvent('mousemove');
```

This also works but is deprecated:

```
const event = document.creatEvent('touchstart');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Mazza Dawson

The createEvent method is being deprecated like you mentioned. You can still use document.createEvent as long as the event that you pass into the method, is on the list.  Here is the list of event types you can pass into the createEvent method. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

The 'touchstart' event type does not exist within the list that is given.  I believe you are referring to 'ontouchstart' which is a method that can be executed on individual elements that exist within the DOM.  Documentation for ontouchstart can be found here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchstart

I hope this helps you out.  Have a great day.

Comment: It's not a problem with the event name, it's a problem with the constructor.